# How to find out the logged in user in workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, workflow

I have a sequential workflow in SharePoint 2013. I want to update a list item field with the name of the user who modified a specific workflow task.

How can I get this done in c#?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method ??

If you are wanting to get the current user when you log in you can try something like this

```
 SPWeb webSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(SPContext);

 SPUser spUser = webSite.CurrentUser;

 string strUserName = spUser.LoginName;
```

Or try this :

```
 string ModifiedbyUserName = Convert.ToString(workflowProperties.Item.GetFormattedValue("Modified By"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: The following solution doesn't work for "Site Workflows"

```
public static SPUser GetCurrentUserInWorkflow(Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties)
{
   string ModifiedbyUserName = Convert.ToString(workflowProperties.Item.GetFormattedValue("Modified By"));
   string[] strChar = { "ID=" };
   string[] strChars = ModifiedbyUserName.Split(strChar, StringSplitOptions.None);
   Int32 iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(strChars[1].Substring(0, strChars[1].IndexOf("\"")));
   SPUserCollection usersInSite = workflowProperties.Web.SiteUsers;
   int countUsers = usersI nSite.Count;
   for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= countUsers - 1; iCnt++)
   {
     if (usersInSite[iCnt].ID == iUserID)
     {
       return workflowProperties.Web.SiteUsers[iCnt];                    
     }
   }
   return null;
 }
```

the above code is for checking last user who modified workflow item. If you want to find current user on workflow start, then you can use:

```
workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.ID
workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.Name
workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.ID.LoginName
```

Comment: Im modifying the workflow item via the task input in the workflow.

Comment: I tried it and still I end up getting 'System Account' :-(